# Simplejson on mac os x 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, pip, osx-mavericks

I've been spending a day in order to install simplejson package. Always I'm without success!

When I type :

```
pip install simplejson
```

It raised me error :

```
Installing collected packages: simplejson
Running setup.py install for simplejson
building 'simplejson._speedups' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c simplejson/_speedups.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-intel-2.7/simplejson/_speedups.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
```

Has some one ever met error like this, or can give me advice what i can do in order to install it?

Comment: Hm, cant really see the error in that. It is just giving a warning the the arg is not used during the compilation. I have just tried on mavericks and it worked nicely. What message do you get after the warning line ?

Comment: Where exactly do you see an error? There aren't any in the log you showed—and when I run it, after that warning and another one and various other lines, it ends with "Successfully installed simplejson" (and then "Cleaning up...").

Comment: Also, is there a reason you need `simplejson` instead of the stdlib `json` module? You obviously don't need Python 2.5 compatibility if you're installing into Python 2.7.

Comment: It's just stopped at that point.. It seems for me it goes in infinity loop.

Comment: When I break it by myself I've got it `Operation cancelled by user
Storing complete log in /Users/dusanristic/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: When I open pip.log file I've got [pip.log-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6epziaqymsobyv0/Screenshot%202013-11-05%2019.17.02.png)

Comment: That is strange, which versions of pip and setuptools are you running ? `pip --version`, `easy_install --version`

Comment: `pip --version` : _pip 1.4.1 from /Users/dusanristic/.virtualenvs/np4.2.2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)_

Comment: `easy_install --version` : _setuptools 0.9.8_

Comment: Hm thats fairly new, (setuptools is now at 1.1.6, but i doubt the upgrade would solve this), have you tried installing it using easy_install ? `easy_install simplejson`

Comment: Here is what happen when I try to install through easy_install, just stop at one point and do nothing : [easy_install report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0e37em08aoumna/Screenshot%202013-11-05%2019.31.18.png)

Comment: Dont really know what is going on, it may be compiler related, i am using `clang`, seems like you are using `cc`. Have you tried installing any other packages that requires compiling of c extensions ? Really hard to debug this :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40595/discussion-between-prog-dusan-and-jbub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we managed to fix the problem on the chat. It was problem related to upgrading to OS X mavericks and this article was really helpful http://attentionshard.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/os-x-mavericks-fixing-broken-python-development-environments/.

Comment: Yea, problem was related with old Xcode's version(4.6) and OS X Mavericks.I needed to upgrade my Xcode. Thank you !

Comment: Thank you! I've spent hours searching to find this answer.